# TSQL - Rank Values but return Column Names

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table of data points that I need ranked by column.
I have about 500k Id's and 25 columns (as of now).
I'd like to make the query dynamic so that any added columns will not require a code change.

[image: Table:]

For each ID, I want to find column names of the top 3 values.

The results should be:

| [Id] | [Rank1] | [Rank2] | [Rank3] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 27807745 | Value3 | Value2 | Value8 |
| 96448378 | Value6 | Value5 | Value1 |
| etc |  |  |  |

My first attempt was to create a joined table of Id's and column names:

| [Id] | [Value1] | [Value] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 27807745 | Value1 | NULL |
| 27807745 | Value2 | NULL |
| 27807745 | Value3 | NULL |
| 27807745 | Value4 | NULL |
| 27807745 | Value5 | NULL |

Then run a looped update, then sequence by `Id, Value DESC`.
This gets me there but is taking over 2 hours to complete.

I looked at `PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT` but both want to return the values, not the column names.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Please consider not posting [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of code or data. We cannot copy or use data from a picture.

Comment: If you can change the schema, do so. Use rows, not columns, for the values. When you need to add more values you don't add more columns, you just add more rows. Your table will consist of three columns: `Id, Name, Value`. Then you can do things like `outer apply (select top 3...)`. No dynamic sql required.

Comment: "My first attempt was to create a joined table" - please show us as it helps clarify the question and we can see where you are going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option that will dynamically unpivot your data ***WITHOUT*** using Dynamic SQL

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=aa4a8ce42f7c2fb157d90fe43e570aa8)**

```
Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
               Select Rank1 = max(case when Rnk=1 then [Key] end)
                     ,Rank2 = max(case when Rnk=2 then [Key] end)
                     ,Rank3 = max(case when Rnk=3 then [Key] end)
                 From (
                        Select [Key]
                              ,Value
                              ,Rnk = row_number() over (order by convert(int,value) desc)
                         From OpenJson((Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper )) 
                         Where [Key] Not IN( 'ID','Other','Columns','ToExclude')
                      ) B1
             ) B
```

Comment: @lptr I see what you are saying.  good catch.   small fix.   Updated